# I'm getting the following error in My mapreduce code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to get pearson's correlation for all pairs of column.
This is My MapReduce code :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Pearson 
{   
    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IndexPair,ValuePair>{
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
             String line = value.toString();
             String[] tokens = line.split(","); 
             double[] arr = toDouble(tokens); 

             for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              for(int j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
               IndexPair k2 = new IndexPair(i, j);
               ValuePair v2 = new ValuePair(arr[i], arr[j]);
               context.write(k2, v2);
               } 
              }
            }
            public double[] toDouble(String[] tokens) {
             double[] arr = new double[tokens.length];
             for(int i=0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
              arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(tokens[i]);
             }
             return arr;
        }
    }
    public static class MyReduce extends Reducer<IndexPair,ValuePair,IndexPair,DoubleWritable>
    {
        public void reduce(IndexPair key, Iterable<ValuePair> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
             double x = 0.0d;
             double y = 0.0d;
             double xx = 0.0d;
             double yy = 0.0d;
             double xy = 0.0d;
             double n = 0.0d;

             for(ValuePair pairs : values) {
              x += pairs.v1;
              y += pairs.v2;
              xx += Math.pow(pairs.v1, 2.0d);
              yy += Math.pow(pairs.v2, 2.0d);
              xy += (pairs.v1 * pairs.v2);
              n += 1.0d;
             }
             double numerator = xy - ((x * y) / n);
             double denominator1 = xx - (Math.pow(x, 2.0d) / n);
             double denominator2 = yy - (Math.pow(y, 2.0d) / n);
             double denominator = Math.sqrt(denominator1 * denominator2);
             double corr = numerator / denominator;
             context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(corr));
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Pearson's Correlation");
            job.setJarByClass(Pearson.class);
            job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
            job.setCombinerClass(MyReduce.class);
            job.setReducerClass(MyReduce.class);

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IndexPair.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(ValuePair.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(IndexPair.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

And Code for IndexPair is this one :

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public  class IndexPair implements WritableComparable<IndexPair>{
        public static String[] labels
                            ={"Year","Month","MEI","CO2","CH4","N2O","CFC-11","CFC-12","TSI","Aerosols","Temp"};
        public long i,j;
        public IndexPair()
        {

        }

        public IndexPair(long i,long j) {
            this.i=i;
            this.j=j;
        }
        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            i = in.readLong();
            j = in.readLong();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeLong(i);
            out.writeLong(j);
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(IndexPair o) {
            Long i1 = i;
            Long j1 = j;
            Long i2 = o.i;
            Long j2 = o.j;

            int result = i1.compareTo(i2);
            if (0 == result) {
                return j1.compareTo(j2);
            }

            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Corelation between column "+labels[(int) i]+"-->"+ labels[(int)j];
        }

    }
```

And Code For value Pair is thisone :

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class ValuePair implements WritableComparable<ValuePair>{

        public double v1,v2;
        public ValuePair()
        {

        }
        public ValuePair(double i,double j)
        {
            v1=i;
            v2=j;
        }
        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            v1=in.readDouble();
            v2=in.readDouble();
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeDouble(v1);
            out.writeDouble(v2);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ValuePair o) {
            // comparator for value pair is not required....
            return 0;
        }

}
```

But Whn I'm trying to execute this, I'm getting the following error

```
17/07/20 13:59:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/07/20 13:59:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1500536519279_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable is not class ValuePair
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner$OutputConverter.write(Task.java:1728)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at Pearson$MyReduce.reduce(Pearson.java:66)
    at Pearson$MyReduce.reduce(Pearson.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the reducer as a combiner:

```
job.setCombinerClass(MyReduce.class);
```

The output key and value types of the combiner should be the same as the ones of the mapper, while, when you use the reducer as a combiner, it tries to emit pairs of different types, hence the error.